# Controlling versions with Maven

Tags: maven

I have 3 `poms` in my projects, 1 for parent and 2 for each of the `modules` in use.

Each pom currently contains `<version>2.1.9.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` tag

**Is it possible for each of the modules to pull this information form the parent automatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [versions-maven plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) as described here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/5726599/320180

Answer (score 1):

In a multi-module build only the parent should define the versions of the artifacts except in the parents.

```
  +-- root (pom.xml)
        +-- mod-1 (pom.xml)
        +-- mod-2 (pom.xml)
```

So the root pom.xml looks like (excerpt):

```
   <project...>
    <groupId>project.com.root</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    ...
```

every module (mod-1) pom.xml looks like (excerpt):

```
   <project...>
     <parent>
       <groupId>project.com.root</groupId>
       <artifactId>project-parent</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
     </parent>

     <artifactId>mod-1</artifactId>
```

In particular the version should never be mentioned in the childs. The changing of the version number at all should be done via the [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/) during a release cycle. Sometimes it can happen that you change the groupId in the childs in larger projects with quite large number of modules.