# Maven release:prepare fails with "scm connection or developerConnection must be specified"

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

I'm trying to prepare a release of my maven project with `mvn release:prepare` but it fails with the following error:

> *Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: Missing required setting: scm connection or developerConnection must be specified.*

After reading about these settings on maven.apache.org, I see that there are SVN (Version Control) settings. 
But I'm not using version control. How should I make a maven release in this case?
I'm using maven 3.0.3.

Comment: Don't you use any version control? I wonder how a release management can work without one.

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically. What does a 'release' mean to you? There might be better ways to achieve what you want without using the release plugin.

Comment: I want my maven project to go from 1.0-SNAPSHOT to 1.1-SNAPSHOT, and that maven generates the jar for my 1.0 version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating version numbers of modules in a multi-module Maven project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726291/updating-version-numbers-of-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project)

Comment: i am using GIT for version control still i do see this error.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you only would like to change the version, the [Versions Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) may help.

The [versions:set](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/set-mojo.html) may be the good one for using.

***Please take a big note, since you're not using the SCM, please make a full backup before using the following command.***

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0 
mvn clean install
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.1-SNAPSHOT 
mvn clean install
```

Anyhow I highly recommend and encourage you to use the SCM and perform the release by following the Maven good practice instead.

I hope this may help.

Comment: this doesn't auto increment though or does it ?

Comment: @muzijack It just set to any version which we want.

Comment: For multi-module projects, you might add `-DprocessAllModules=true` to update all child modules.

Answer (score 16):

May your pom.xml not having the entry

```
    <scm>        
    <connection>scm:svn:https://host:port/abc/xyz/trunk</connection>
 <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://host:port/abc/xyz/trunk</developerConnection>
    </scm>

<build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <tagBase>https://host:port/abc/xyz/tag</tagBase>
                        <releaseProfiles>release</releaseProfiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>               
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to add your SCM configuration. In the example below I added my git repository to the master branch

```
<scm>
    <developerConnection>
        scm:git:git@github.com:tufac2/sfg-pet-clinic.git
    </developerConnection>
</scm>
```

Comment: Does it work if I don't have master access?

Answer (score 0):

In Springboot the answer depends of plugin that you are using

> docker-maven-plugin:

- mvn docker:build

> dockerfile-maven-plugin:

- mvn dockerfile:build

I hope this help you

Regards