# Maven multi-module + inheritance: Issue in building submodules when maintaining parent version number via placeholders

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

This is rather a follow-up for [this answer on maintaining parent version numbers via placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17312681/maven-multi-module-project-version-management#17312851):

I am on Maven **3.6.1**, and have the following multi-module Maven project structure:

```
pom.xml
a/
  pom.xml
b/
  pom.xml
```

`pom.xml` (parent):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tuna</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>${ver}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>a</module>
        <module>b</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <ver>1.0-SNAPSHOT</ver>
    </properties>
</project>
```

`a/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tuna</groupId>
        <artifactId>root</artifactId>
        <version>${ver}</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
    <version>${ver}</version>
</project>
```

`b/pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tuna</groupId>
        <artifactId>root</artifactId>
        <version>${ver}</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>b</artifactId>
    <version>${ver}</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tuna</groupId>
            <artifactId>a</artifactId>
            <version>${ver}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Note that `b` depends on `a`.

Now, when I build this with

```
mvn clean install
```

it gets built successfully (with some `'version' contains an expression but should be a constant` warnings - fair enough).

However, if I do

```
mvn clean install -rf :b
```

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.tuna:a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.tuna:a:${ver}, C:\Users\janaka\code\dustbin\mvn-multi-module\a\pom.xml, line 15, column 14
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.tuna:root:${ver}, C:\Users\janaka\code\dustbin\mvn-multi-module\pom.xml, line 9, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.tuna:b:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.tuna:b:${ver}, C:\Users\janaka\code\dustbin\mvn-multi-module\b\pom.xml, line 15, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.tuna:root:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'version' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ com.tuna:root:${ver}, C:\Users\janaka\code\dustbin\mvn-multi-module\pom.xml, line 9, column 14
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]



[INFO]
[INFO] -----------------------------< com.tuna:b >-----------------------------
[INFO] Building b 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.472 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-09T00:08:14+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------



[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project b: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tuna:b:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.tuna:a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.tuna:a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact com.tuna:root:pom:${ver} has not been downloaded from it before. -> [Help 1]



[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

The same happens if I run `mvn clean install` from within `b/`.

Apparently Maven *can* resolve `${ver}` for both `b` and `a`, but when it scans `a`'s POM it fails to resolve `a`'s *parent's* `${ver}` version (although the `relativePath` entry is there); probably because Maven is reading `a`'s POM from the local repository (`~/.m2/repository/` - where the relative path won't make sense) and not from the local codebase?

Is there a way to get this to work - avoid the error and get partial builds working - maybe via some hack; like passing a default value for `${ver}` via a system property?

**P.S.:**

Yeah yeah, I know it's all smelly and evil to use placeholders in parent version number; but my actual project has around 30 modules, many of which are inter-dependent on others. So I just want a way to maintain a single version number (one line) which I can change easily - without having to change and commit a couple hundred lines every time I upgrade.

Basically I'm not asking for suggestions to replicate the version number all over the place instead (and use something like Maven versions plugin to upgrade them all at once) - I just need a hack to get the current structure working.

(So I believe this cannot be flagged as a duplicate - because replication and placeholders are the only two options I came across in SO, and my question is about a specific case of the latter. )

Answer (score 2):

If it is only to maintain a single version across the whole project then you can use `revision` placeholder.

The parent must declare it and children can inherit it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.tuna</groupId>
    <artifactId>root</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>a</module>
        <module>b</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <revision>1.0-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>
</project>
```

And your a/pom.xml do not need to declare the placeholder property again. You just use parent revision.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.tuna</groupId>
        <artifactId>root</artifactId>
        <version>${revision}</version>
        <relativePath>..</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>a</artifactId>
</project>
```

Read more at https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html#Multi_Module_Setup

Comment: Thanks!
But it still doesn't work for partial builds (`-rf :b`, or building `b` directly).
Fails with the same error as before:
`Failed to execute goal on project b: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.tuna:b:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at com.tuna:a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.tuna:a:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Cannot access central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) in offline mode and the artifact com.tuna:root:pom:${revision} has not been downloaded from it before.`

Comment: Why are using partial build when you can build using `-pl` ? Also you are in offline mode.

Comment: I need to build all remaining modules, hence `-rf :` instead of `-pl`; and offline mode is fine, as I already have all dependencies available locally.

Comment: Just confirmed `-pl` gives the same error as well. (Besides, keeping aside `-pl`, `-rf :` etc., I should be able to build a single module (e.g. `cd b/ && mvn clean install`) - which doesn't currently work, either with `${ver}` or `${revision}`.)

Comment: @JanakaBandara Did you find a resolution to this?  I am having the same issues with mvn 3.6.3

Comment: @Eric I ended up overriding (in root POM) the `maven-resources-plugin` execution to make a copy of each POM, replacing all placeholders (`<execution><id>copy-resources</id><phase>validate</phase><goals><goal>copy-resources</goal></goals><configuration><resources><resource><directory>.</directory><include>pom.xml</include><filtering>true</filtering></resource></resources><outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory></configuration></execution>`) and also `maven-install-plugin` to use/install the fixed copy instead of the original (`<configuration><pomFile>target/pom.xml</pomFile></configuration>`)

Comment: @JanakaBandara want to stick this as an answer so I can upvote? (How bizarre two people in two days wanting an answer to a two year old question!)

Answer (score 0):

Just mentioning my final workaround, in case it helps someone:

I ended up overriding the `maven-resources-plugin` execution to make a copy of each POM, replacing all placeholders (config added to root POM so that it applies to all submodules):

```
<!-- replaces version number placeholders in POMs, with current values -->
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.1</version>
  <execution>
    <id>copy-resources</id>
    <phase>validate</phase>
    <goals>
       <goal>copy-resources</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration combine.children="append">
      <resources>
        <resource>
          <directory>.</directory>
          <include>pom.xml</include>
          <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
      </resources>
      <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
  </execution>
</plugin>
```

I also override `maven-install-plugin` to use/install this modified (fixed) copy from `target/`, instead of the original with placeholders:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4</version>
  <configuration combine.children="append">
    <pomFile>target/pom.xml</pomFile>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now the POMs installed to local/remote repos are free from placeholders; so any dependent project/module would be able to process those POMs successfully! In a sense I believe this is the right approach, because in my case the placeholders are only there for the developer's convenience; and there is actually no reliable way to resolve their values once they are installed into a Maven repo.

One downside is that *all* placeholders get resolved; e.g. if a POM contained a `${java.home}` expression, the installed copy now contains the actual absolute path to the builder machine's Java installation. I still did not find a proper way to exclude such (a subset of) placeholders from being replaced.