# maven-multi-module-inheritance-issue-in-building-submodules-when-maintaining parent version using placeholders

Tags: java, maven, installation, pom.xml

```
main-project/
      module1/ 
           sub-module1/
           submodule2/
      module2/
           sub-module3/ depends on sub-module1/
           sub-module4/ depends on sub-module2/
           sub-module5/
      module3/
      module4/
```

I have a multimodule Project main-project have a pom which contains version property.i definded main as a parent in module2 and module2 has parent in submodule 4.when i trying to build the project from root pom version property is getting resolving.but when i am building submodule4 version property of submodule2 is not getting resoved.i tried with fatten plugin it working but don't want to you flatten plugin.tried with below snippet working fine took from [Maven multi-module + inheritance: Issue in building submodules when maintaining parent version number via placeholders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296447/maven-multi-module-inheritance-issue-in-building-submodules-when-maintaining) but i don't want to hard code the POm name in install-plugin. as my each individual module  contain different POMs defined parent in each(worked fine with flatten plugin) any recomendation to overcome this ..using maven 3.3.3 version

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- <version>3.0.1</version> -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration combine.children="append">
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>.</directory>
                                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                            <outputDirectory>target</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration combine.children="append">
                    <pomFile>target/pom.xml</pomFile>
                    </plugin>
```

I have a multimodule Project main-project have a pom which contains version property.i definded main as a parent in module2 and module2 has parent in submodule 4.when i trying to build the project from root pom version property is getting resolving.but when i am building submodule4 version property of submodule2 is not getting resoved.i tried with fatten plugin it working but don't want to you flatten plugin.tried with about snippet working fine but i don't want to hard code the POm name in install-plugin.any recomendation to overcome this ..using maven 3.3.3 version

I am overiding maven resource plugin to copy all pom files with resolved properties to target folder but during  installation i don't want to hardcode the folder and pom file name  i do have other poms also for installation so want to avoid hardcoding of  target/pom.xml

Comment: First why are you copying things via resources plugin? What is the intention of that? Put resources into `src/main/resources` and they will be packed into the resulting jar by default...furthermore what is the purpose of the configuration in maven-install-plugin ? Also why using such old versions? Please show the full pom file and describe why and what you like to achieve?

Comment: I was actaully trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58296447/maven-multi-module-inheritance-issue-in-building-submodules-when-maintaining) issue. I have a multiModule Project and trying to maintain version number in one POM and all child should get it .when trying to build a sub module version number is not getting resovled.

Comment: That is unrelated to the maven-resources-plugin and why you configured maven-install-plugin. Apart from that why using a hard location `target/pom.xml`. Please describe more in detail what you like to achieve...best with a full working example on github/gitlab etc...

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Please make a full working example on github because the given things you describe ` main as a parent in module2 and module2 has parent in submodule 4` will not work because a module can only have a single parent ... `.i tried with fatten plugin it working but don't want to you flatten plugin.` ? You are telling you don't want to use a plugin? Why? As described here: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html