# Jenkins artifactory plugin doesn't change version of modules to next development version

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, release, artifactory

I have a project structure described in [Updating version numbers of modules in a multi-module Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726291/updating-version-numbers-of-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project) and as it is described there `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=2.50.1-SNAPSHOT` works perfectly. However when I press the button on the [Jenkins UI in Artifactory Release Staging](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Artifactory+Plugin+-+Release+Management) all submodules and the parent are released to Artifactory with the correct release version however only the parent's `pom.xml` is changed and pushed to git with the next development version (SNAPSHOT), all children `pom.xml` remain unchanged.

How can I make sure version is updated to the next development version in all `pom.xml` (just as if I ran `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=<nextVer>-SNAPSHOT`) and pushed to git (in every submodule and the parent as well)?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the issue using jfrog [maven-example](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/maven-example).
Can you share a sample maven project so we will try to reproduce the issue?

Comment: @tamir-hadad After a quick look I could spot the following differences in the `pom.xml` in [maven-example](https://github.com/JFrogDev/project-examples/tree/master/maven-example) compared to mine: I have `relativePath` tag in `parent` tags and in submodules `version` tags not only in `parent` but also in `project` (as in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726291/updating-version-numbers-of-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project)). So a snippet from my parent:

Comment: So a snippet from my [parent](http://codepad.org/OAOE7xas) and one of the [children](http://codepad.org/4nEudz9j).

Comment: I still didn't manage to reproduce the issue, even when using relative path and version per module.
If you can please provide us a sample project in Github or contact JFrog support.

Comment: @tamir-hadad Oh I think I know the major difference: I have git modules not plain folders.  So for instance `b_b` is in a separate repo and is referenced in the git repo (`.gitmodules`) containing the parent pom `b-parent.pom`.