# Updating version numbers of modules in a multi-module Maven project where the aggregate root isn't a parent pom

Tags: java, maven, multi-module

I want to set a release version for my project. I use an aggregate pom for all modules. Each module parent is not the aggregate pom mentioned before.

My question differs from [Updating version numbers of modules in a multi-module Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726291/updating-version-numbers-of-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project) question, there the aggregate pom is a parent pom as well.

The aggregate pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>aggregate</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>module1</module>
    </modules>

</project>
```

Where the module1 pom.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>module-1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../../parent1/pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

</project>
```

When I execute:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=0.0.1

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO]
[INFO] module-1
[INFO] aggregate
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building aggregate 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.3:set (default-cli) @ aggregate ---
[INFO] Searching for local aggregator root...
[INFO] Local aggregation root: C:\Users\maxim.kirilov\workspace\maven-games\aggregate
[INFO] Processing change of com.example:aggregate:0.0.1 -> 0.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] module-1 ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] aggregate .......................................... SUCCESS [  0.962 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
```

Why module-1 is skipped? I read some articles that suggests to invoke the maven set version command for each module separately, does maven support for cleaner solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently (23/09/2017) a documentation was added to Versions Maven Plugin. In order to update all project under aggregate project you need to add supplemental command line parameters:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=0.0.1 -DoldVersion=* -DgroupId=* -DartifactId=*
```

This is needed otherwise the filter for the versions (via -DoldVersion=*) would have filtered out that module cause it has a different version than the rest of modules. Furthermore you need to add the -DgroupId=* and -DartifactId=* otherwise the **module-1** will also filtered out based on the differences in groupId and artifactId.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to include Versions Maven Plugin in your aggregate pom xml.
http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/
http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html

something like this i do:

```
 <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3</version>
      <configuration>
     <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
     </configuration>
    </plugin>
 </plugins>
```

Comment: I don't find any kind of configuration like `autoVersionSubmodules` in the docs? This is only available in [maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html) but not in [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Suggest you to read further on the second link, something like mvn -N versions:update-child-modules may help you. As of now you can ignore autoVersionSubmodule, but i have used both plugins : releasr and version with above code, it works cool

Comment: autoVersionSubmodule is not a configuration item which is in versions-maven-plugin available. It is only available in maven-release-plugin. From versions-maven-plugin it will simply being ignored.

Comment: Yes..it is part of release plugin and i have written to ignore it as of now if you don't want to use it..but i gave you other hint i.e. mvn -N version update-child-moduldes..did you try this?

Comment: No its not useless, rather depends on use case. You need to understand whole maven release process.

Comment: Maxim Kirilov,Could you please remove down/negative voting

Comment: This configuration option is simply not supprted by versions-maven-plugin at all. So you can simply remove it.

Comment: thanks. this fixed my issue. this way it set the version for all the modules as opposed to just the parent before