# How to update child pom version using maven and jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have created a jenkins job where I am passing ReleaseNumber as a parameter, I want this ReleaseNumber to be updated in every pom.xml file (root and child pom), since I am uploading these wars in nexus repository, same version number wont be accepted by nexus.
I want to update child pom version and parent pom version as well.
I am using maven 3.5

I am using this command which I think its not working

```
mvn org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin:2.5:set -DnewVersion-${ReleaseNumber}
```

This is my parent pom looks like

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test.test</groupId>
<artifactId>Wars</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

and this is my child pom looks like

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.test.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestWar</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test.test.testwar</groupId>
<artifactId>TestWar</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>testWar</name>
```

[image]

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What do you mean by "which I think its not working"?

Comment: @JFMeier I mean this command is not updating my pom version number

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Updating version numbers of modules in a multi-module Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726291/updating-version-numbers-of-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project)

Comment: @suneel What does it write to the log? Any errors?

Comment: @JFMeier it doesnt give any errors, just some warnings since it doesnt update version in all child pom so it is not able to find parent pom then it gives error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a variable ${ReleaseNumber} defined in pom? Or you just copy/pasted it?

You have typo, not - but =

`-DnewVersion=${ReleaseNumber}`