# Maven overwrite version tag

Tags: maven, jenkins, msbuild, release

In my project's POM file, there are some tags

```
<groupId>foo.bar</groupId>
<artifactId>foobar</artifactId>
<version>X</version>
<description>foo bar foo bar</description>
```

specified. I'm doing some builds using Jenkins and I want to overwrite that `X` value. How can I do that?

As an example, I'm more familiar with MSBuild and there I can do something like

> msbuild.exe project.sln ...some options... /p:AssemblyVersion=X

Is that AssemblyVersion that I'm talking about. Is this possible with maven?

Besides that, is this even a good practice? At the moment, I have version `1.0-SNAPSHOT`. Should I manually change that value? How to perform a release?

Comment: Have a lookmat the maven release plugin: https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update version in pom files automatically from Jenkins, use `-DnewVersion` argument along with `mvn` command.
Example:

```sh
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=someversion
```

During buildtime, if you'd like to update the buildnumber as your artifact version, then you can just pass that environment variable like `-DnewVersion=${BUILD_NUMBER}`.

Edit 1:
Credits to this SO thread [updating-version-numbers-of-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5726599/10363259). It has a clear explanation.