# How to only bump up the maven project version on git with maven release plugin?

Tags: java, git, maven, maven-release-plugin

I want to automatically bump up the version, such that on each release a new version is tagged on the commit and the main branch is set to the next SNAPSHOT version.

The usual release:prepare, release:perform also deploys the artifacts to a binary repository. However, I only want to bump up the version and push to git and not deploy the artifacts anywhere. I get the following error as I don't have a  in my pom.xml (as my intention is not to deploy anywhere).

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project rp-demo-app: Deployment failed: repository element was not specified in the POM inside distributionManagement element or in -DaltDeploymentRepository=id::layout::url parameter -> [Help 1]
```

I am running `$ mvn release:prepare release:perform`

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/perform-mojo.html#goals

Comment: @BoristheSpider, do I need to set the <configuration.goal> to something specific?

Comment: I’ll leave that as an exercise to the reader. Hint: what is it set to by default and what behaviour do you want to change?

Comment: @BoristheSpider From deploy to install?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating version numbers of modules in a multi-module Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726291/updating-version-numbers-of-modules-in-a-multi-module-maven-project)

Comment: @Joe nope......

Answer (score 0):

remove the release:perform and only run with release:prepare , it is enough for your usecase.

if you want to re-run release from the beginning at every run, add release:clean :

mvn release:clean release:prepare